# How can I make android studio very fast?

Tags: java, android, macos, android-studio, jvm

I have added the file /Users/Jim/Library/Preferences/AndroidStudio/studio.vmoptions
With the following:

```
-Xms2048m
-Xmx4096m  
-XX:MaxPermSize=350m  
-XX:ReservedCodeCacheSize=96m  
-XX:+UseCompressedOops
```

I am not seeing a dramatic performance difference from the default. How do I know if these options are being used? Also are the rest of the options (premises and reservedcodechache) reasonable or too low?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately it is not possible to achieve a dramatic performance improvement for Android Studio by changing the VM options. If it was possible at all, then the developers of Android Studio would have included those options in the default distribution - no one likes to waste an opportunity to make their product faster.

If there are specific areas where you see inadequate performance, you're welcome to report performance problems to Google or JetBrains, and usually there are workarounds or ways to help. But in general, the only way to make such a product very fast is to get a very fast computer.

To see how much memory is actually being used by Android Studio and how much is available, you can enable the memory usage indicator using Settings | Appearance | [x] Show memory monitor.

Comment: But how can I know that at least my configuration for heap size are being used? Or that the small permsize I configured is wrong?

Comment: The permsize is either sufficient (in which case Android Studio runs) or insufficient (in which it shows an out of memory dialog). If you don't see the out of memory dialog, then the permsize is sufficient. Increasing it further brings no benefit at all. As for the other memory settings, you can enable Settings | Appearance | Show memory monitor and see how much memory is available and used.

Comment: So increasing the heap size would not make it faster? What's the idea behind this configuration setting then?

Comment: First of all, this setting is not specific to Android Studio; every Java application allows to specify the memory size. Second, just like every other Java application, Android Studio needs to have enough memory to store the data it needs to keep in memory. If it doesn't have enough, its performance will be poor. But there's no benefit to allocating much more memory for it than it needs to use.

Comment: The default -Xmx setting in Android Studio has been chosen so that it has enough memory for the majority of projects.

Comment: That's weird. I always thought the IDEs tries to cache as much as possible and so the more memory the better

Comment: The size of the data that can be cached in a useful way is not unlimited.

Comment: What about page swaps?Isn't that heap part of that?

Comment: No, quite the opposite. Memory you allocate for the JVM can't be used for disk cache and for other needs of the operating system.